# Can't pip install mysqlclient error on Mac

Tags: python, pip

I'm unable to install `pip install mysqlclient` and it returns an error. I want to use the Connector/Python.

```
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/chichong/MyProject/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-install-uelq41i2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-install-uelq41i2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-record-qsanuzxd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/chichong/MyProject/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient
         cwd: /private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-install-uelq41i2/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/include/mysql -I/Users/chichong/MyProject/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.18_1/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/chichong/MyProject/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-install-uelq41i2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-install-uelq41i2/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/84/s5lsk989351b8w9j2pjttrb80000gn/T/pip-record-qsanuzxd/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/chichong/MyProject/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.

======================================

Package                Version
---------------------- ------- 
Django                 3.0.1  
mysql-connector-python 8.0.18 
pip                    19.3.1 
PyMySQL                0.9.3  
sqlparse               0.3.0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ld%3A+library+not+found+for+%22-lssl%22

Comment: I fixed an issue related to the openssl, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have openssl installed. Try `brew install openssl`

If you're still getting the error when openssl is installed you'll probably need to:

`brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force`

and then run the `export LDFLAGS` and `export CPPFLAGS` comands it outputs.